# Maxscript / cant write string in middle of text file

Tags: maxscript

Hi Guys i tried to add something to middle of a text file like this :

```
fs = openFile "D:\Projects\Exports\Map\info.txt" mode:"a+"
skipToString fs "line3"
skipToNextLine fs
print "Hello" to:fs
close fs
```

my text file is like this :

line1
line2
line3
line4
line5

and i want to add "hello" after line3 text. but it always add the text to the end of the file:

line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
"Hello"

anyone know what is the problem ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mode:"a+"` will always append the file in the end of file. Try this:

```
fs = openFile "D:\Projects\Exports\Map\info.txt" mode:"r+"
skipToString fs "line3"
format "Hello" to:fs
close fs
```

This will overwrite the characters after "line3", so you need to use `substitutestring` or something else. I changed `print` to `format` as `print` adds a new line after the "Hello". There is no need for `skipToNextLine`, it will position the cursor to next line in the file.